# Finding the vector normal to curve in this question to find acceleration

Tags: vectors, parametric, classical-mechanics

[image]

I am confused of how to find acceleration in this question where only certain random information are given.

I tried using the $a(π/2) = a_{t}\cdot T + a_{n}\cdot N$, and I got $a_t = 1/2, T = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)}$<-1,0,1>, and $a_{n} = 3*T'(π/2)$. However, I cannot find $T'(π/2)$. Is there a way to find this? or is there another method to solve for acceleration.